# javascript regex replace multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have an input string as

```
var x= "(toInteger(r.Time) > 1501570800000) AND (toInteger(r.Time) < 1517385600000 )"
```

With a regex , I am able to find the numbers (more than 4 in length) :

```
var regex = /(\d{4,})/
regex.exec(x)
```

How to change those two numeric values as per input (min,max)

```
function (min,max){
x=x.replace(regex,"$1","$2");
}
```

so that , if min=1501570800022 and max=1517385600023 , then expected output is:

```
"(toInteger(r.Time) > 1501570800022) AND (toInteger(r.Time) < 1517385600023 )"
```

Comment: Regexes match patterns. They don't do math.

Comment: why isn't there a regex tag if this is regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.prototype.replace`  using callback function which will replace matching group with each iteration so we need to return min for first iteration and `max` for 2nd iteration.

```js
var x= "(toInteger(r.Time) > 1501570800000) AND (toInteger(r.Time) < 1517385600000 )";
var regex = /(\d{4,})/g;

function replace(min, max) {
   var iteration = 0;
   return x.replace(regex, () => {
      return arguments[iteration++]; // arguments is build in and contains all arguments passed to current function
   });
}

console.log(replace(123, 456));
```